# Celery only used 1 thread

Tags: celery, celery-task

I'm writing a Celery server and I want to use Celery's built-in concurrency capabilities.
I understand that by performing the following:

```
server_app.conf.update(worker_concurrency=4
```

You can achieve 4 working threads that will concurrently perform the task reading.
I ran my server and sent it 5 tasks but from the Logs I see that all of them are handled by the MainThread:

```
[2023/09/26 14:16:21 MainThread 404524 celery_client.py INFO] {'error': 'Invalid Code 5'}
[2023/09/26 14:16:22 MainThread 404524 celery_client.py INFO] {'error': 'Invalid Code 4'}
[2023/09/26 14:16:24 MainThread 404524 celery_client.py INFO] {'error': 'Invalid Code 3'}
[2023/09/26 14:16:27 MainThread 404524 celery_client.py INFO] {'team': 'OPS'}
[2023/09/26 14:16:31 MainThread 404524 celery_client.py INFO] {'team': 'BE'}
```

Why is that? I want to be able to distinguish between the different threads that perform the reading to be able to view logs for each thread but it only uses 1 instead of 4.

I tried to play with the number and it was the same. as I understand it is supposed to be done automatically by celery so I don't understand why isn't it working as I expect it to.

Comment: What did you configure concurrency type to be? Also, how do your run your Celery worker (please give us the full command).